# post.length stays 0 due to loop - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, loops, pagination

I'm trying to add pagination but I can't seem to figure out this last part.
Everything is setup, though my pagination isn't recording the amount of posts that are linked with the user.

Seeing that I'm doing a forEach and if loop and pushing the retrieved items into a empty collection, my 'posts.length' is returning 0.

Hence the pagination only showing page 1/1 and not 1/2 (for example).

Here is my full code:

**profileCtrl.js**

Here is the $http.get - I'm trying to get all the posts that the logged in user made doing this loop:

```
app.controller('profileCtrl', function($scope, auth, $http, $log) {

    $scope.auth = auth;
    $scope.date = auth.profile.created_at;
    $scope.pageSize = 5;
    $scope.posts= [];

    $http.get('URL')
        .then(function(result) {
            angular.forEach(result.data, function(data, key) {
                if(data.userId === auth.profile.user_id) {
                    $scope.posts.push(data);
            } 
        });
    });
});
```

**profile.html**
As you can see, I'm trying to get the length of post in posts using `total-items="posts.length"`:

```
<div class="col-md-8 no-padding-right">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="list-group-item active text-center">
            <h4 class="no-margin-top no-margin-bottom">Recent Activity</h4>
        </div>

        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="post in posts| startFrom: (currentPage - 1) * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize | orderBy :'created_at':true">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail no-border no-margin-bottom">         
                        <img src="https://placehold.it/150x150" alt="bird" width="150" height="150"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h4 class="no-margin-top no-margin-bottom"><strong>{{post.birdname}}</strong></
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <uib-pagination total-items="posts.length" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="pageSize" boundary-link-numbers="true"></uib-pagination>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.js**
I also added a filter in app.js:

```
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
  return function(data, start) {
    return data.slice(start);
  }
});
```

When I `console.log(posts.length);` I keep getting 0 and I'm guessing it's because of the `$scope.posts = [];` declared on top (profileCtrl.js).

**Edit:**

After doing a bit of debugging with console.log, I do get the value given when doing this:

```
$http.get('url')
        .then(function(result) {
            angular.forEach(result.data, function(data, key) {
                if(data.userId === auth.profile.user_id) {
                    $scope.posts.push(data);
            } 
        });
        console.log($scope.posts.length);
    });
```

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>If you're waiting for data to be returned before loading the collection (with pagination) either add a `ng-if="posts.length"` to the container, or initialise `$scope.posts` as being `null` and add `ng-if="posts"` if you want the list to show when the API returns 0 results. This will prevent Bootstrap's pagination directive being parsed until the data it needs is available.</strike>

**Edit:** After debugging, the following plunkr contains a working implementation: http://plnkr.co/edit/VQjNVK6gRKsCqxVb54nR?p=preview

Comment: Your comment makes little sense, prevent $scopes showing? From what you've said it seems that the pagination directive isn't detecting the change in the value bound to `total-items` so my suggestion was to delay the rendering of the pagination component until the posts array has been populated, which is what you'd expect to see anyway.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say was, this simply prevents the pagination of showing if no posts are found. The delay doesn't solve it though. (deleted my comment above because it indeed didn't make any sence, sorry)

Comment: Are you able to throw together a plunkr demonstrating? Because everything seems to be okay if delaying doesn't resolve.

Comment: I added a second edit on the bottom. when doing this console.log, the item returned gives the correct amount from the database. I'll try setting up a plunkr

Comment: Alright, I'm also trying with a plunkr and I'm having the same issue, i'll keep on it

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/VQjNVK6gRKsCqxVb54nR?p=preview

Is this as you are expecting?

Comment: It's showing all the posts made, it's not filtering the userId (if I'm not mistakening)

Comment: The plunkr above does filter out posts where the user ID is not equal to the auth value (posts ID 2 & 3 don't show in the paginated result). I substituted your forEach loop for Array.filter() as it is a little cleaner

Comment: Updated everything as posted in the plnkr and it works. Thanks for the help.